# Handle the change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am stuck and need help.  I have 5 text boxes: `txt1`, `txt2`, `txt3`, `txt4` and `txt5`, and there is a function `func1()`.  I want that if there are any changes in any of these text boxes then the function `func1()` will be called. Can you please help me with how I can do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Answers below are good. If you happen to be unaware of [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), you should check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link the **onchange** event to your **func1()**

It will be something like:

```
<input type="text" onchange="func1()">
<input type="text" onchange="func1()">
<input type="text" onchange="func1()">
<input type="text" onchange="func1()">
<input type="text" onchange="func1()">
```

(The id/name was not written.)

Answer (score 3):

You could subscribe to the `onchange` event in those textboxes and call the function:

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" onchange="func1();" />
<input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" onchange="func1();" />
...
```

or do it unobtrusively:

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" />
...
```

and then in your javascript file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('txt1').onchange = func1;
    document.getElementById('txt2').onchange = func1;
    ...
};
```

or in a loop:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        document.getElementById('txt' + i).onchange = func1;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am Using This code 
in which Input Item is the array containing the Ids of text boxes and isRequestValid is before the call of function. Is it correct?
**bold**
'code'
$(input_item).each(function() {
    // Save current value of element
    if ($(this).data('oldVal') != $(this).val()) {
     isRequestValid = true;
     $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val());
    }
   });

Comment: @user1179868, that's jquery code. Why haven't you explained this in your original question? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 3):

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

 function function1()
 {
 alert("changed");
 }

 </SCRIPT>

 <INPUT NAME="txt1" onChange="function1()"><BR>
 <INPUT NAME="txt2" onChange="function1()"><BR>
 <INPUT NAME="txt3" onChange="function1()"><BR>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the reference to the element then

```
    <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" onchange="func1(this);" />
    <input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" onchange="func1(this);" />

function func1(item){
  // you have the reference to the item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see every answer using the "onchange" events in HTML. This is bad practice. See [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to understand why.

I'd recommend using `document.getElementById('').addEventListener('change', function() {});`, but the cross-browser support of this is not the best, so this is why I recommend using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

In jQuery, you just add the same class to your textboxes, and you can do this :

```
$('.textBoxes').change(function() {});
```

I usually don't recommend jQuery when somebody asks for javascript, but this case clearly asks for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange`. `<input type="text" id="txt1" onchange="func1()" />`

See [JavaScript Event onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Comment: I am Using This code 

[code]
$(input_item).each(function() {
    // Save current value of element
    if ($(this).data('oldVal') != $(this).val()) {
     isRequestValid = true;
     $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val());
    }
   });
[code]
in which Input Item is the array containing the Ids of text boxes and isRequestValid is before the call of function. Is it correct?

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question and add this code snippet for everyone to see. Use http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Btw, if you're using $(this) then you're using jQuery. Refer to http://api.jquery.com/change/ for jQuery change function.